# Which source or sources expand the elementalist wizard's spell lists?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard, product-identification

The Advanced Player Guide introduced Wizard Elemental Schools, along with spell lists associated with those schools. For example, for the Air School, the following level 1 spells are given:

Alter Winds, Feather Fall, Shocking Grasp

However, looking at the list of spells for the Air School in [Archives of Nethys](https://aonprd.com/SchoolDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Air), it includes several additional spells (emphasis mine):

> 1st - **air bubble**, alter winds, feather fall, **gentle breeze**, shocking grasp, **windy escape**

The same thing happens over many other levels of spells and other elemental schools.

I understand these spells were added after the Advanced Player Guide  was released which explains the discrepancy. However, looking at the sources for these individual spells I couldn't find any mention on whether they should be added to the school lists (they are simply usually listed in the generic sorcerer/wizard list)

Further, the list shown in the Archives of Nethys (the [official reference](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6sg93?Big-PathfinderStarfinder-Reference-Document-News)) also includes more spells than the [d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/elemental-arcane-schools/air/) reference.

Note that I don't want to find the sources for the spells themselves (which is trivial). What I want is to find the source(s) where the spells are actually added to the elemental school lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The elemental schools spell lists got updated in Planes of Power

It's from [Planes of Power Campaign Setting](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9ng0) (sidebar on page 9), which says:

> Some wizards choose to master one of the elemental
>   forces rather than one of the classic schools of magic
>   (Pathfinder RPG Advanced Player’s Guide 142, Pathfinder
>   RPG Ultimate Magic 87). **The following list presents
>   a number of spells introduced since those books
>   were published that also belong to these respective
>   elemental schools**.
>
> Any: 3rd—communal resist energyUC. 4th—communal
>   protection from energyUC.
>
> Air: 1st—**air bubble**UC, **gentle breeze**ACG, **windy
>   escape**ARG; 2nd—aggressive thundercloudACG, gusting
>   sphereARG; 3rd—air geyserACG, hostile levitationUC;
>   4th—absorbing inhalationARG, cloud shapeARG, greater
>   aggressive thundercloudACG, miasmatic formARG; 5th—
>   fickle windsUM, lightning arcUM, wind bladesARG; 6th—
>   path of the windsARG; 7th—scouring windsUM; 9th—ride
>   the lightningUM.
>
> Earth: 1st—corrosive touchUM, mudballARG, stone
>   shieldARG, thunderstompACG; 2nd—molten orbACG, stone
>   discusACG; 3rd—burrowUM, greater thunderstompACG, heart
>   of the metalACG, raging rubbleARG; 4th—earth glideARG,
>   obsidian flowUC, vitriolic mistUM; 5th—acidic sprayUM,
>   communal stoneskinUC, corrosive consumptionUM; 6th—
>   tar poolUC; 7th—caustic eruptionUM.
>
> Fire: 1st—touch of combustionARG; 2nd—fiery shurikenUC,
>   molten orbACG; 3rd—ash stormUM, fire streamARG, fire trailARG,
>   flash fireUC; 4th—controlled fireballUI, greater flaming
>   sphereACG, obsidian flowUC, scorching ash formARG, volcanic
>   stormUM; 5th—damnation strideARG; 6th—chains of fireARG,
>   tar poolUC.
>
> Metal: 1st—body capacitanceACG, mirror polishACG,
>   reinforce armamentsUC, shock shieldUC; 2nd—aggressive
>   thundercloudACG, bullet shieldUC, bullet wardACG, warding
>   weaponUC; 3rd—pellet blastUC, silver dartsACG; 4th—
>   greater aggressive thundercloudACG, named bulletUC; 5th—
>   wreath of bladesUC; 6th—greater named bulletUC; 7th—
>   arcane cannonUC, awaken constructOA.
>
> Water: 1st—damp powderUC, icicle daggerUM, marid’s
>   masteryARG, wave shieldACG; 2nd—frigid touchUM, frost
>   fallUC, river whipACG, unshakable chillUM; 4th—ride the
>   wavesUM; 5th—icy prisonUM; 6th—cold ice strikeUM,
>   ice crystal teleportUM; 7th—ice bodyUM; 9th—mass
>   icy prisonUM.
>
> Wood: 1st—cultural adaptationUI, handy grapnelUI,
>   illusion of calmUC, liberating commandUC, quintessenceOA;
>   2nd—companion life linkACG, extreme flexibilityACG, life
>   pactACG, squeezeARG; 3rd—air geyserACG, anchored stepACG,
>   pack empathyUI; 4th—lesser age resistanceUM; 5th—mass
>   charm personUI, plant shape I; 6th—age resistanceUM,
>   plant shape II, serenityUM; 7th—greater age resistanceUM,
>   plant shape III; 9th—wooden phalanxUM.

Comment: Amazing. I had been looking for this everywhere. Even mailed Archives of Nethys to ask about it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I also e-mailed him when this was first asked, then searched all my core books, player companion and campaign setting that had anything to do with elementals or arcane casters. Today, checking the books I had not read yet, I found this.